# Play audio using if statement

Tags: php

Hey guys was looking for a good way to wind up a friend and I had the idea of a song he hates playing every time he opened his userdetails.php

this is the code

```
if ($CURUSER['id'] == 1)
stderr( "<embed name='Barbie Girl' src='/music/barbie.mp3' loop='true' hidden='true' autostart='true'/>

<font size=3>Sorry Brother Couldn't Resist </font>");
```

The only issue is it halts the page there and I have been trying to make it play the song and show the page

Any help would be greatly appreciated its nothing huge just a fun little wind up I would like to finish

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `stderr` should be replaced by `echo`.

Second, `embed` might not be supported in this case, try the html5 [Audio](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp) tag instead since it's supported in all current browsers. Best of all, use an "ogg" audio file, it plays in all browsers.